# BASH test if file name ends with .dylib

Tags: bash

I'm walking a file tree in order to identify all .DYLIB files.

```
#!/bin/bash

#script to recursively travel a dir of n levels

function traverse() {
for file in "$1"/*
do
    if [ ! -d "${file}" ] ; then
        echo "${file} is a file"
    else
        echo "entering recursion with: ${file}"
        traverse "${file}"
    fi
done
}

function main() {
    traverse "$1"
}

main "$1"
```

I want to test if the filename ends with .DYLIB before printing "... is a file". I think I may need to add to the condition "if [ ! -d "${file}" ] ; then", but I'm not sure. Is there a way to do this in bash?

Comment: You mean you need to print `"${file} is a file"` only if the file ends with `.dylib`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add to the condition in `if [ ! -d "$file" ]`, because then the `else` block will try to recurse into files that don't have the suffix. But recursion should only be for directories.

You should add a nested condition for this. You can use bash's `[[ ]]` condition operator to have `=` perform wildcard matching.

```
if [ ! -d "${file}" ] ; then
    if [[ "$file" = *.DYLIB ]]; then 
        echo "${file} is a file"
    fi
else
    echo "entering recursion with: ${file}"
    traverse "${file}"
fi
```

Or you could invert the sense of the directory test:

```
if [ -d "$file" ]; then
    echo "entering recursion with: ${file}"
    traverse "${file}"
elif [ "$file" = *.DYLIB ]; then
    echo "$file is a file"
fi
```

Comment: Well, you can use `[ "${file##*.}" = "DYLIB" ]` and kinda fudge it that way in bash `:)`

Answer (score 4):

No need to write your own recursive function. You can recursively find all `*.dylib` files using a `**` glob:

```
shopt -s globstar
ls "$1"/**/*.dylib
```

Or use `find`:

```
find "$1" -name '*.dylib'
```

To use these results I recommend looping over them directly. It avoids using up memory with a temporary array.

```
shopt -s globstar

for file in "$1"/**/*.dylib; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

or

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do 
    echo "$file"
done < <(find "$1" -name '*.dylib')
```

---

> Is there a way I can store everything in a string array so that I can perform an operation on those .dylib files?

But if you do indeed want an array, you can write:

```
shopt -s globstar
files=("$1"/**/*.dylib)
```

or

```
readarray -td '' files < <(find "$1" -name '*.dylib')
```

Then to loop over the array you'd write:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: Is there a way I can store everything in a string array so that I can perform an operation on those .dylib files? In the end, I need the list of file paths so that I can run codesign on them via bash rather than having to do it manually (there are ~100 dylib files).

Comment: Just note when using `find`, the order of the files are not preserved in the same order they would be when using the `globstar` approach.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this solution to work. I tried installing homebrew and adding globstar, but the "files=("$1"/**/*.dylib)" just said no files or directories found.